# Measure current ripple over shunt, legit?

Tags: current-measurement, oscilloscope, power-measurement

I'm thinking of using a calibrated shunt and then measure the current ripple by measuring the voltage over the shunt, with an oscilloscope.

I'm assuming a differential probe would be the best choice to go by.

The thing I want to achieve with measuring this way instead of my other option current probe is a wider bandwidth and to measure faster rise and fall times or the current.

However I'm a bit unsure about the Pros and cons of doing so? compared to a current probe.

Comment: This is effectively a current probe. You could use a differential amplifier or an oscilloscope in differential mode (thereby using its internal differential amplifier. By a "current probe" I assume you mean a non contact probe using eg a Hall cell. This is effectively a floating probe which measures electromagnetic field rather than voltage. Differences in result such as bandwidth are a result of the differing technologies but you are effectively doing the same thing in each case.

Comment: This will work, although the quality of the results depends on many things. In particular, if the voltage amplitude is very low, you may have a hard time seeing the signal above the noise. A differential probe will give the best result, but there are ways to do this with single-ended probes, also.

Comment: Note that current probes are available with excellent bandwidth (in the MHz range). I haven't priced one in a while, and I am sure they are at least several hundred dollars (or a few thousand). So if buying one is an option, that is definitely a good way to go.

Comment: @mkeith The ones I see are $1k+ for 300kHz and $5k for 120MHz. or else I would have one for home. I don't even particularily like the 300kHz one. The 120MHz one is nice to use though, and for what it cost it better be.

Comment: Sounds right. At my last job we bought a used techtronics one from ebay for not too much. Can't remember the specs. Maybe 50 Amps DC-5 MHz for a few hundred bucks. So used is an option.

Comment: You guys are rich.;)

Answer (score 1):

Good question! A shunt measurement is definitely a valid way of doing things, but it's tough to nail down specifically how accurate your measurements will be with that approach.

From a probe standpoint, it depends on how large your current is. We actually just put together a video about measuring current with an oscilloscope:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oOB1rgJMCN8

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in the current ripple, and not its DC component, a current transformer would actually be my choice. Most current transformers aren't designed for very high frequencies, but I know at least that [Pearson](https://pearsonelectronics.com/products/wideband-current-monitors) makes some that have bandwidths in the hundreds of megahertz. They're not *cheap*, of course, and you can't just go buy one on digikey--you have to ask for a quote and go through that whole process--but they're still much cheaper than current probes from Tek or LeCroy. Think on the order of $500 instead of $5000.

There are probably other companies that make similar current transformers, but this is the only one I'm aware of.

---

Note: I am in no way affiliated with Pearson; I just learned about these recently and would have loved to have known about them sooner, because current probes are *expensive*.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm thinking of using a calibrated shunt and then measure the current ripple by measuring the voltage over the shunt, with an oscilloscope.

This is effectively a current probe.
You could use a differential amplifier
or an oscilloscope in differential mode (thereby using its internal differential amplifier.

By a "current probe" I assume you mean a non contact probe using eg a Hall cell.  This is effectively a floating probe which measures electromagnetic field rather than voltage. Differences in result such as bandwidth are a result of the differing technologies but you are effectively doing the same thing in each case.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to measure ripple to > 20 MHz SMPS ripple with a load << 50 Ohms is to measure with an AC coupled 50 ohm coax terminated with 50 ohms. This may be better than a CT with limited BW.

This way, probe inductance to ground is eliminated from noise pickup as long as your coax attachment uses say 1cm jumpers. With ~ 8 nH /cm and coax ~ 110 pF/m which affects the BW.

This can be done with no special equipment except a pigtail to BNC coax , C for AC coupling 50 Ohm R 1/4W, and a BNC T to insert R at DSO.

This is the Best cheap and dirty high BW current ripple sensor.

If your current sense is not grounded , then you need two caps to isolate both sides of coax. This gives you a balanced differential high BW response that is accurate.

Dupe [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/398817/what-should-i-buy-to-test-whether-my-dc-power-supplies-are-able-to-provide-their/398832#398832):

But for high impedance signals, balancing two probes in A-B mode for a flat trace both on the same signal will work as well as your probe calibration to null A-B.

You can then use a transistor current sink to vary step load and see the transient response sync triggered  to scope, with DC on the other channel filtered to 20 MHz. Then vary the step size with bias current , or use a power FET with step voltages.